# try not or do not try?

Tags: grammar

> Why not take the elevator? climbing the stairs will fatigue you.

I wonder what is the subject of the clause?

In addition:

Are these the same?

> I try not to make errors.
>
> I do not try to make errors.

Moreover, when usually do you prefer to use the following structure(S) like above?

VERB+NOT+ TO VERB

Comment: 1) Please ask two questions if you have two questions. 2) please visit http://ell.stackexchange.com where your questions are more likely to fit

Comment: 'Why not take the elevator?' is an acceptable sentence fragment. It has no subject. (Some might say there is an 'implied subject': 'Why do **you** not take the elevator?')

Comment: "Climbing the stairs will make you (feel) tired." It's not idiomatic to say: *it will fatigue you*. Sentence 2) could imply that the person makes no effort in making errors, that he makes errors is a fact. But in speech, I suspect many would interpret this as having the same meaning as the sentence 1).

Answer (score 4):

> I try not to make errors.
>
> I do not try to make errors.

These are subtly different.

The first implies that you are putting effort towards not making errors.

The second implies that you are putting no effort towards making errors.

In general, the first is probably what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Nima_Persian,

I had also the Same Query in several times. Because Here in my Place, I saw People preferring to use VERB + NOT + To VERB as like as in Sentence 1  in most of the cases rather than using Sentence 2 ?.

For Instance:

Sentence 1: I try not to drive my car in an inefficient Manner.

Sentence 2: I don’t try to drive my car in an inefficient Manner.

Are both of these are same and formal?  and Is there difference between these Sentence ?.

I Checked with my Tutor, He has cleared my doubt on this , I am sharing that answer to you here.

1. Both the sentences mean the same.
2. ‘Verb + not to’ (Sentence 1) is used in highly formal diction.
3. It (Sentence 1) puts emphasis on the verb and makes the reader / listener focus in on the statement.
4. He advised me that, We can use this statement in writing and speaking (Sentence 1)

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences do not mean the same thing. The first one focuses on making an effort to avoid doing an undesirable act. The second one states that no effort is made to do that undesirable act.